# SQL - Aggregating over time series

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to find aggregate per second data for a field in a table which may have one or more records every second, as in table1:

table1

```
   Time             field1
   09:37.43.755       0      
   09:37.44.256       0     
   09:37.44.757       0    
   09:37.44.758       1
   09:37.45.756       0
   09:37.45.759       1
   09:37.46.758       1
```

The table2 output expected is below. The `field1_agg` shall have one value for every second - based on the rule for aggregating -> count of number of 1s / count of number of 0s, with the exception that if the count of number of 0s is zero, then the filed1_agg for that second shall be 1.

table2

```
   Time             field1_agg 
   09:37.43.000      0.0   #=> count of field1 = 1 / count of fied1 = 0 in all rows with 09:37.43.xxx -> 0/1 = 0
   09:37.44.000      0.5   #=> count of field1 = 1 / count of fied1 = 0 in all rows with 09:37.44.xxx -> 1/2 = 0.5
   09:37.45.000      1.0   #=> count of field1 = 1 / count of fied1 = 0 in all rows with 09:37.45.xxx -> 1/1 = 1.0
   09:37.46.000      1.0   #=> if count of field1 = 0 is zero in all rows with 09:37.46.xxx, then 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `date_trunc()` to round the `time` column to seconds.  The rest is just aggregation and some conditions:

```
select date_trunc('second', time) as time,
       (case when max(field1) = 0 then 1
             else sum(field1) / sum(1 - field1)
        end) as field1_agg
from table1
group by date_trunc('second', time)
order by date_trunc('second', time);
```

Note:  I simplified the logic, assuming that `field1` takes on values of only 1 or 0.  You can be more explicit:

```
(case when sum(case when field1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 0
      else (sum(case when field1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) /
            sum(case when field1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
           )
  end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked. Try it.

```
SELECT dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, time), time) time,
       SUM(CASE field1 WHEN 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 end)/
       (case SUM(CASE field1 WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 end) WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE SUM(CASE field1 WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 end) END) field1_agg FROM table1
       GROUP BY dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, time), time)
```